# Is there a way to limit output of Tags related to an entry?

Tags: tags

I've checked it with [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tagmodel#properties) but, tag model doesn't have `limit()` property as entries have.

Wondering, If there is any way around to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A limit doesn't make sense on a single element model. But all ElementCriteriaModels have a `limit` parameter and for `craft.tags` it is [documented here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.tags#limit).

To limit the tags related to an entry via a Tags field don't use the [shortcut syntax](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/tags-fields#templating):

```
{% set tags = entry.tagsFieldHandle %}
```

But modify the `craft.tags` ElementCriteriaModel instead:

```
{% set tags = craft.tags({
    relatedTo: { sourceElement: entry, field: "tagsFieldHandle" },
    order:     "sortOrder",
    limit:     null
}) %}
```

Comment: I was just about to modify the question just to your freshly updated answer. Nice job!

Comment: Copied it from the [docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/tags-fields#templating) ;)

Comment: Whatever, You helped, even if It was there.